# Why does System.out.println(String) not print anything?

Tags: java, string

I have some code in my java IDE and I believe that it has support for console. I have used java before and know the ins and outs. However, this problem has not occured with me before. My code looks like this:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Choose a class.");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    System.out.println("Press 1 for the a class.");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    System.out.println("Press 2 for the b class.");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    System.out.println("Press 3 for the c class.");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);

    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            playerClass.chosenClass = "a";
            break;
        case 2:
            playerClass.chosenClass = "b";
            break;
        case 3:
            playerClass.chosenClass = "c";
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Null class. Please press 1-3 to choose a player class.");
    }
}
```

I have all the imports, and the playerClass class does exist. The problem is, the "System.out.println(String)"'s do not work.

Comment: I have used java before and know the ins and outs -> it seems something missing between in and out.

Comment: Please make sure to read [MCVE] guidance before asking new questions. I.e. for this question 2 lines that demonstrate the problem would likely show you what is wrong without even asking the question.

Comment: Got it. Can't delete though.

Comment: And, Sundararaj, yeah, something probably is. I haven't done Java in like a year. I guess it's one of those skills that deteriorates over time if not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might want to do is set your logic more like:

```
System.out.println("Press 1 for xx, 2 for xx, or 3 for xx");

if(scanner.hasNext()){
    choice = scanner.Int();
}

if(choice == 1){
     //do whatever;
}
else if(choice == 2){
     //do whatever;
}
```

I might not be understanding your question right but I think you need to make sure you keep everything in order.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I did, as show by EJP, and it did help. Although you did seem a little less critical about it. Thanks, by the way. On being less critical then EJP.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the prompt after accepting the input. And as you haven't seen the prompt yet, you probably aren't typing any input. So you never get past `Scanner.nextInt()`.

Your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Understood, don't tend to use the Scanner class.

Comment: By the way, I don't need you to tell me that my code doesn't make sense. Because it doesn't. I knew that. That's why I came here. Think about it. would I seriously come here thinking that my code made complete sense if the computer can't read it? I just wrote it before posting.